# Assign variable in rspec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, controller, factory-bot

I have an rspec test in which I need to test my controller.

```
it "renders the #show view" do
  get :show, id: FactoryGirl.create(:quiz)
  @facebook_profile = FactoryGirl.create(:facebook_profile)
  response.should render_template :show
end
```

The facebook_profile object has a user_q1 column, so @facebook_profile.user_q1 gives a valid result.

In my quiz controller:

```
@user_q1 = @facebook_profile.user_q1
```

This works fine in manual testing, but in rspec, I get the result:

```
undefined method `user_q1' for nil:NilClass
```

I suspect the issue is here, in the first line of my show method in the controller:

```
@facebook_profile = FacebookProfile.find_by_facebook_id(session[:facebook_profile_id])
```

I have a variable in my session controller (although not a column in any model) that I call facebook_profile_id. I then call this variable in the above line of code in my quiz controller. I think my spec can't define @facebook_profile because it doesn't know facebook_profile_id. Apparently just defining "@facebook_profile = FactoryGirl" (like I have above) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should proceed this way:

```
let(:fb_profile) { FactoryGirl.create(:facebook_profile) }
let(:quiz) { FactoryGirl.create(:quiz) )

it "renders the #show view" do
  FacebookProfile.should_receive(:find_by_facebook_id).and_return fb_profile
  get :show, id: quiz.id
  response.should render_template :show 
end
```

Actually you don't need to create objects in db, but that's another debate.